# onPress = display.remove not working on Corona SDK

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk

I am a beginner to corona sdk and lua. So i was working on a program and faced the following problem:

```
local buttonSmall = widget.newButton
{
id = "smallBtn",
defaultFile = "buttonBlueSmall.png",
overFile = "buttonBlueSmallOver.png",
label = " Next",
fontSize = 12,
emboss = true,
onPress = display.remove(button1)

}
```

The problem is that i want to remove button 1 when i click "buttonSmall" but whenever i launch my code in the sdk it does not show the button without even clicking the "buttonSmall"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not assigning a function to the `onPress` listener. You are executing `display.remove(button1)` and assigning whatever that returns to the `onPress` which is `nil`. You need to wrap your function call, like so:

```
onPress = function()
    display.remove(button1)
end,
```

or like this:

```
local function deleteButton1()
    display.remove(button1)
end

...

onPress = deleteButton1,
```

So that is why your `button1` never shows up, you already deleted it by calling `display.remove()`. Remember, widget expects to have a function assigned to it on `onPress`, and you can do that by simply specifying the function name or making a funcion right there.

Comment: Great! Consider marking as the correct answer. Glad to help!

Comment: but dude what if I want to remove all the buttons by clicking ButtonSmall?

Comment: You will have to declare a reference to the buttons above the function, so that it can access them.

Comment: Don't know why my answer was unaccepted, since it fixes the problem and addresses all points asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inline function like below:

```
local buttonSmall = widget.newButton
{

id = "smallBtn",

defaultFile = "buttonBlueSmall.png",

overFile = "buttonBlueSmallOver.png",

label = " Next",

fontSize = 12,

emboss = true,

onPress = function()display.remove(button1)end

}
```